# Transpiling code to JavaScript in a controlled environment

Tags: javascript, parsing, dsl, transpiler

So I have a DSL language that transpiles to javascript, there is however a catch, every time that a function is ran, the control must be given to the execution environment which will decide if to run the function, skip it, or terminate the entire program. For example a piece of code from the language may look like this.

```
y = 2*r
value = draw(y)
r = 2
```

this would transpile to something like this (readability incremented):

```
(function(){
    ASSIGN(["y"], MUL(NUMBER(2), VAR(["r"])));
    ASSIGN(["value"], CALL(["draw"],[VAR(["y"])]));
    ASSIGN(["r"], NUMBER(2));
})
```

Now the thing is that draw is an async function, it needs time to draw the thing, however javascript will execute those things immediatly, but I don't want to, and blocking the entire thread doesn't seem like a good idea.

The solution I was thinking was of using generators, if I'm not mistaken about their usage

```
(function* (){
    yield START();
    ASSIGN(["y"], MUL(NUMBER(2), VAR(["r"])));
    ASSIGN(["value"], yield CALL(["draw"],[VAR(["y"])]) );
    ASSIGN(["r"], NUMBER(2));
    yield DONE();
})
```

So that the execution environment has the control as:

```
let app = myApp();
//process does the async stuff
let executor = new Executor(app);
executor.run();

class Executor {
    constructor(app){
        this.app = app;
        this.next();
    }
    next(value){
        this.process(this.app.next(value), this.next);
    }
    process(function_statment, resume){
        //Do the async stuff here
        resume('value');
    }
}
```

Beautiful :3

However that's not especially the most compatible method for the current browsers, apparently generators are not widely supported.

As my last resort I'd use.

```
(function (EENV){
    EENV(START(),function(){
        ASSIGN(["y"], MUL(NUMBER(2), VAR(["r"])));
        EENV(CALL(["draw"],[VAR(["y"])]), function(value){
           ASSIGN(["value"], value);
           ASSIGN(["r"], NUMBER(2));
           EENV(DONE(),function(){});
        });
    });
})
```

But this is way more unreadable, even if I used events, it'll still be that way, which would make it hard to debug the transpiler (to check the code, perform unit tests, etc...) because it's making such a callback hell.

And the execution environment would be like.

```
myApp(function(statment, callback){
   //DO ASYNC STUFF
   callback(someValue);
});
```

Do you have other solution or ideas? That would hopefully be similar to the yield?

Comment: I found the best optimal solution was to put all the instructions in an array and use the execution environment to loop through them.